# Redux devtools extension error when dispatching @ngrx/router-store action

Tags: ngrx, redux-devtools-extension

I'm using the following libraries:

- Angular 4
- @ngrx/router-store
- @ngrx/store-devtools

Just recently, when trying to dispatch a `go` router action with the `relativeTo` set to the current active route:

```
go(['test', id], {}, {relativeTo: this._active}))
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: toISOString is not a function
    at String.toJSON (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (shim.js:736)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5166)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5605)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5605)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
    at derez (<anonymous>:2:5787)
```

It seems there is a problem with the devtools handling the `ActivatedRoute` in the payload (similar to [this issue](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/315)).

If I implement a new version of the `go` action creator (as suggested here: [Redux Devtools Extension Troubleshooting](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#it-fails-to-serialize-data-when-passing-synthetic-events-or-calling-an-action-directly-with-redux-actions))to add a `toJSON` function to the `NavigationExtras`, then it all works:

```
go(path: string|any[], query?: any, extras?: NavigationExtras): any {
    extras['toJSON'] = function(): any {
        return { ...this, relativeTo: this.relativeTo.snapshot.url };
    };

    const payload = { path, query, extras };
    return { type: routerActions.GO, payload };
}
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**UPDATE:** Looks like it also has something to do with lazy-loaded routes.  The error only happens if the current route is part of a lazy-loaded module (i.e. via `loadChildren`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're passing a React Synthetic Event, which cannot be serialized. See the similar issue and the troubleshooting. Note that the solution in that issue will not be available in React 16, since we're relying on React internals. So, I recommend to choose one of the solutions from the [troubleshooting.](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#it-fails-to-serialize-data-when-passing-synthetic-events-or-calling-an-action-directly-with-redux-actions)

However, it would be great if we could make jsan not to throw in this case, but at least to skip those data. If you could add a pr with a test case there, it would be much appreciated. Seems like the issue with toISOString is only for specific events as I wasn't able to reproduce.

Comment: I was able to resolve using the link provided.  Also, this same problem was referenced in discussions for https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/12, so hopefully it will be resolved by the framework soon

Answer (score 0):

The redux-devtools is trying to parse a function as json would normally work but it suppose that everything in the store are objects and not functions so it breaks the basic idea of ​​redux is to manage states for events use the emission of functions use standard of angular